# From a nutrition perspective, is microwaving frozen vegetables without water the same as microwaving frozen vegetables with water?

Tags: microwave

Similar to this question, except I'm asking about nutritional content instead of just taste: [Is it ok to microwave veggies without water instead of blanching them in a pot of water?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/19309/is-it-ok-to-microwave-veggies-without-water-instead-of-blanching-them-in-a-pot-o)

I'm wondering if microwaving veggies without water denatures some nutrients, or something like that.

Comment: Why the downvotes on the question?

Answer (score 0):

I think nutrients can be anything from fibrous cellulose, volatile oils, unsaturated fats, organic compounds like vitamin C, and microwaving is just vibrating water molecules. I don't know if microwaving can denature nutritious proteins, which are typically 'denatured' by enzymes, but, incase it does have that effect, then I'm sure frying, searing, roasting might have some similar effect. So either you cook it or eat it raw!

You may be better off scouring scientific articles.